# como imprimir imagen en php con mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

tengo el siguiente código que me lista todos mis registros:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <th width="41%">Id</th>
        <th width="46%">Categoría</th>
        <th width="46%">Nombre</th>
        <th width="46%">Precio</th>
        <th width="46%">Diseño</th>
        <th width="46%">Concepto</th>
        <th width="13%">Opcion</th>
    </tr>
<?php 
    $sql = "select * from stickerb";
    $result = db_query($sql);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_object($result)){
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->id_sti;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->categoria_sti;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->nombre_sti;?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->preciboom;?></td>
        <td><?php echo "<img src='".$row["patternim"]."' width='100' heigth='80'>";?></td>



        <td><?php echo $row->destacado;?></td>
        <td>

<a class="btn btn-primary" href="editar.php?id=<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="borrar.php?id=<?php echo $row->id;?>"><i class="fa fa-trash-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Todo funciona bien pero al momento de imprimir el campo de imagen me da el siguiente error:

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion\Insertar Editar Eliminar Registros con Función PHP MySQLi\index.php:86 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gestion\Insertar Editar Eliminar Registros con Función PHP MySQLi\index.php on line 86

Si coloco la variable de foto de esta forma: patternim;?>

Si me funciona pero solo me trae la ruta de la imagen.

Como podría hacer para que me traiga la imagen?

Comment: El procedimiento es el correcto pero todos los trataste como objetos y el ultimo como array, ese es el problema

Comment: Hola, tal como dice @JonathanOrta escribes `$row["patternim"]` y debes escribir `$row->patternim`

Answer (score 0):

Estás accediendo incorrectamente a la propiedad "patternim" de tu objeto $row, y si es que en tu base de datos solo guardas el nombre y extensión de tu imagen deberías también proporcionar la carpeta donde se almacenó tu imagen, correctamente sería:

```
<td><?php echo "<img src='/carpeta/de/imágenes/" . $row->patternim . "' width='100' heigth='80'>";?></td>
```